# Blank App : Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a weird problem.

I narrowed it to a mere blank Xamarin forms project. I can run it on my Android api 22 (Samsung Core prime) and on a simulator but I cannot deploy it on my Android api 23 (Asus Zenfone 3).
I get `Index was outside the bounds of the array` in the error panel. I tried on my mac and on my pc.

This is what I get in the output panel :

```
[E:]:                     Deployment failed
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidInstalledPackage..ctor(String value)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.ParseLastResortPackageList(String output)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass65_0.<GetPackagesLastResort>b__0(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I updated Xamarin to the latest version and Xamarin Forms version is 2.3.4.231

I verified the phone driver and I still have the problem.

This is what I get in the xamarin diagnostic panel :

```
[I:]: Found Xamarin.Android 7.2.0.7
[I:sdk]: Runtime path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
[I:sdk]: Framework path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0
[I:sdk]:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
 Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\).
[I:sdk]:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
 Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121).
[I:sdk]: Looking for Android SDK..
[I:sdk]:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory not found.
[I:sdk]:   Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
 Path does not contain adb in \platform-tools (C:\android-sdk-windows).
[I:sdk]:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\MonoAndroid\PrivateAndroidSdkPath not found.
[I:sdk]:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path not found.
[I:sdk]:   Key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\Path found:
 Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:]: Found Android SDK. API levels: 23, 24, 25
[I:]: Tracking android devices started
[D:]: Tracking avd started
[D:]: TrackDeviceTask got: GBAXGY16K66457B  device
[D:]: avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\danie\.android\avd'
[D:]: avd watcher: got device list from avd with 1 devices
[I:]: Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B getprop
[I:]: Found Android SDK. API levels: 23, 24, 25
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B getprop
-- Start GetProperties - 04/15/2017 23:34:33 (87.6987ms) --
[INPUT] getprop
[OUTPUT]
[af.music.outputid]: [3]
[af.rf_info]: [273]
[asus.hardware.instant_camera]: [1]
[atd.voucher.exist]: [1]
[atd.voucher.intact]: [1]
[audio.wizard.default.mode]: [smart]
[bgw.current3gband]: [0]
[bluetooth.fw.adv.num]: [50]
[bluetooth.fw.energyreport]: [true]
[bluetooth.fw.irk.num]: [128]
[bluetooth.fw.rpa]: [true]
[bluetooth.fw.scanfilter.num]: [50]
[bluetooth.fw.scanresult.size]: [10200]
[bt.version.driver]: [20160413213900a]
[camera.disable_zsl_mode]: [1]
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xms]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xmx]: [512m]
[dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit]: [128m]
[dalvik.vm.heapsize]: [256m]
[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xms]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xmx]: [64m]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm.features]: [default]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm.variant]: [cortex-a53]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.features]: [default]
[dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.variant]: [cortex-a53]
[dalvik.vm.mtk-stack-trace-file]: [/data/anr/mtk_traces.txt]
[dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file]: [/data/anr/traces.txt]
[debug.MB.running]: [0]
[debug.atrace.tags.enableflags]: [0]
[debug.force_rtl]: [0]
[debug.hwc.bq_count]: [3]
[debug.hwc.compose_level]: [0]
[debug.mdlogger.Running]: [0]
[debug.mdlogger.log2sd.path]: [internal_sd]
[debug.mono.extra]: [debug=127.0.0.1:8913:8914,timeout=1492290364,loglevel=0,server=y]
[debug.mtklog.netlog.Running]: [0]
[debug.program_binary.enable]: [1]
[dev.bootcomplete]: [1]
[drm.service.enabled]: [true]
[fmradio.driver.enable]: [1]
[gps.version.driver]: [MNL_VER_16021801ALPS05_3.70_10]
[gsm.baseband.capability]: [503]
[gsm.current.phone-type]: [1,1]
[gsm.gcf.testmode]: [0]
[gsm.network.type]: [Unknown,Unknown]
[gsm.operator.alpha]: []
[gsm.operator.alpha.2]: []
[gsm.operator.iso-country]: []
[gsm.operator.isroaming]: [false,false]
[gsm.operator.numeric]: []
[gsm.project.baseband]: [GR6737M_65_M0_HW(DEFAULT)]
[gsm.project.baseband.2]: [GR6737M_65_M0_HW(DEFAULT)]
[gsm.ril.ct3g]: [0]
[gsm.ril.ct3g.2]: [0]
[gsm.ril.eboot]: [-1]
[gsm.ril.init]: [1]
[gsm.ril.uicctype]: [USIM]
[gsm.ril.uicctype.2]: [USIM]
[gsm.serial]: [E28CC6B2604944   0YYYY0Y0010P]
[gsm.sim.operator.alpha]: [,]
[gsm.sim.operator.iso-country]: [,]
[gsm.sim.operator.numeric]: [,]
[gsm.sim.pin1_count]: []
[gsm.sim.pin1_count.1]: []
[gsm.sim.puk1_count]: []
[gsm.sim.puk1_count.1]: []
[gsm.sim.retry.pin1]: []
[gsm.sim.retry.pin1.2]: []
[gsm.sim.retry.pin2]: []
[gsm.sim.retry.pin2.2]: []
[gsm.sim.retry.puk1]: []
[gsm.sim.retry.puk1.2]: []
[gsm.sim.retry.puk2]: []
[gsm.sim.retry.puk2.2]: []
[gsm.sim.ril.mcc.mnc]: []
[gsm.sim.ril.mcc.mnc.2]: []
[gsm.sim.ril.phbready]: []
[gsm.sim.ril.phbready.2]: []
[gsm.sim.state]: [ABSENT,ABSENT]
[gsm.version.baseband]: [MOLY.LR9.W1444.MD.LWTG.MP.V88.P51, 2017/03/06 10:53]
[gsm.version.baseband1]: [MOLY.LR9.W1444.MD.LWTG.MP.V88.P51, 2017/03/06 10:53]
[gsm.version.ril-impl]: [mtk gemini ril 1.0]
[init.svc.AcdApiDaemon]: [stopped]
[init.svc.DMAgent]: [running]
[init.svc.GoogleOtaAgent]: [stopped]
[init.svc.MtkCodecService]: [running]
[init.svc.NvRAMAgent]: [running]
[init.svc.OperaMaxSystem]: [stopped]
[init.svc.PPLAgent]: [running]
[init.svc.VerifyVouchers]: [stopped]
[init.svc.aal]: [stopped]
[init.svc.adbd]: [running]
[init.svc.agpsd]: [running]
[init.svc.akmd09911]: [stopped]
[init.svc.akmd8963]: [stopped]
[init.svc.akmd8975]: [stopped]
[init.svc.ami304d]: [stopped]
[init.svc.atcid-daemon-u]: [stopped]
[init.svc.audio-daemon]: [stopped]
[init.svc.backuprestore]: [stopped]
[init.svc.batterywarning]: [running]
[init.svc.bluetoothd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.bmm050d]: [stopped]
[init.svc.bmm056d]: [stopped]
[init.svc.bootanim]: [stopped]
[init.svc.bootlogoupdater]: [stopped]
[init.svc.bugreport]: [stopped]
[init.svc.ccci_fsd]: [running]
[init.svc.ccci_mdinit]: [running]
[init.svc.checksilead]: [stopped]
[init.svc.cloudtestsuited]: [stopped]
[init.svc.cmmb]: [stopped]
[init.svc.conn_launcher]: [running]
[init.svc.dbus]: [stopped]
[init.svc.debuggerd]: [running]
[init.svc.debuggerd64]: [running]
[init.svc.dhcp_inform]: [stopped]
[init.svc.dhcpcd_bt-pan]: [stopped]
[init.svc.dhcpcd_p2p]: [stopped]
[init.svc.dhcpcd_wlan0]: [stopped]
[init.svc.dhcpv6_inform]: [stopped]
[init.svc.drm]: [running]
[init.svc.dualmdlogger]: [stopped]
[init.svc.dumpstate]: [stopped]
[init.svc.emdlogger1]: [running]
[init.svc.emdlogger2]: [stopped]
[init.svc.emdlogger5]: [stopped]
[init.svc.emdlogger6]: [stopped]
[init.svc.enableswap]: [stopped]
[init.svc.encrypt]: [stopped]
[init.svc.extmdlogger]: [stopped]
[init.svc.fingerprintd]: [running]
[init.svc.flash_recovery]: [stopped]
[init.svc.fpfslockd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.fpsvcd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.fuelgauged]: [running]
[init.svc.fuse_usbotg]: [stopped]
[init.svc.gas_srv]: [running]
[init.svc.gatekeeperd]: [running]
[init.svc.ged_srv]: [running]
[init.svc.geomagneticd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.gsm0710muxd]: [running]
[init.svc.guiext-server]: [running]
[init.svc.gx_fpd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.healthd]: [running]
[init.svc.hotknot_native]: [stopped]
[init.svc.installd]: [running]
[init.svc.iprenew_p2p]: [stopped]
[init.svc.iprenew_wlan0]: [stopped]
[init.svc.keystore]: [running]
[init.svc.lmkd]: [running]
[init.svc.logcatd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.logd]: [running]
[init.svc.logd-reinit]: [stopped]
[init.svc.mc6420d]: [stopped]
[init.svc.mc64xxd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.md_monitor]: [stopped]
[init.svc.mdlogger]: [stopped]
[init.svc.mdnsd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.media]: [running]
[init.svc.memsicd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.memsicd3416x]: [stopped]
[init.svc.memsicd3524x]: [stopped]
[init.svc.met_log_d]: [stopped]
[init.svc.mnld]: [running]
[init.svc.mobile_log_d]: [running]
[init.svc.mount_apd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.msensord]: [stopped]
[init.svc.mtpd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.netd]: [running]
[init.svc.netdiag]: [running]
[init.svc.nvram_daemon]: [stopped]
[init.svc.orientationd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.p2p_supplicant]: [running]
[init.svc.perfprofd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.permission_check]: [stopped]
[init.svc.poad]: [stopped]
[init.svc.pq]: [running]
[init.svc.pre-recovery]: [stopped]
[init.svc.program_binary]: [running]
[init.svc.qmc5983d]: [stopped]
[init.svc.qmcX983d]: [running]
[init.svc.racoon]: [stopped]
[init.svc.rbfota]: [stopped]
[init.svc.ril-3gddaemon]: [stopped]
[init.svc.ril-daemon]: [stopped]
[init.svc.ril-daemon-mtk]: [running]
[init.svc.s62xd]: [stopped]
[init.svc.servicemanager]: [running]
[init.svc.slpd]: [running]
[init.svc.sn]: [stopped]
[init.svc.start_modem]: [stopped]
[init.svc.stop_modem]: [stopped]
[init.svc.surfaceflinger]: [running]
[init.svc.swapoff_action]: [stopped]
[init.svc.teed]: [running]
[init.svc.terservice]: [stopped]
[init.svc.thermal]: [running]
[init.svc.thermal_manager]: [stopped]
[init.svc.thermald]: [running]
[init.svc.ueventd]: [running]
[init.svc.uncrypt]: [stopped]
[init.svc.usbdongled]: [stopped]
[init.svc.vold]: [running]
[init.svc.vtservice]: [running]
[init.svc.wifi2agps]: [running]
[init.svc.wmtLoader]: [stopped]
[init.svc.wpa_supplicant]: [stopped]
[init.svc.xlogboot]: [stopped]
[init.svc.xlogdebugchanged]: [stopped]
[init.svc.zygote]: [running]
[init.svc.zygote_secondary]: [running]
[keyguard.no_require_sim]: [true]
[mediatek.wlan.chip]: [CONSYS_MT6735]
[mediatek.wlan.ctia]: [0]
[mediatek.wlan.module.postfix]: [_consys_mt6735]
[mtk.md1.starttime]: [1s Sat Apr 15 12:16:56 2017
]
[mtk.md1.status]: [ready]
[mtk.vdec.waitkeyframeforplay]: [1]
[mtk_wifi.fwpath]: [STA]
[net.bt.name]: [Android]
[net.change]: [net.qtaguid_enabled]
[net.hostname]: [android-e2c372064e057965]
[net.nsiot_pending]: [false]
[net.perf.cpu.core]: [4,4,0,0]
[net.perf.cpu.freq]: [1144000,1144000,0,0]
[net.perf.rps]: [ff]
[net.qtaguid_enabled]: [1]
[net.tcp.default_init_rwnd]: [60]
[persist.asus.cb.debug]: [0]
[persist.asus.dclick]: [0]
[persist.asus.gesture.type]: [0000000]
[persist.asus.mobile_slot]: [-1]
[persist.asus.screen.state]: [1]
[persist.asus.swipeup]: [0]
[persist.datashaping.alarmgroup]: [1]
[persist.dm.lock]: [false]
[persist.gemini.sim_num]: [2]
[persist.meta.dumpdata]: [0]
[persist.mtk.datashaping.support]: [1]
[persist.mtk.wcn.combo.chipid]: [0x0335]
[persist.radio.data.iccid]: []
[persist.radio.default.sim]: [0]
[persist.radio.device.imei]: [354224080156720]
[persist.radio.device.imei2]: [354224080156738]
[persist.radio.fd.counter]: [15]
[persist.radio.fd.off.counter]: [5]
[persist.radio.fd.off.r8.counter]: [5]
[persist.radio.fd.r8.counter]: [15]
[persist.radio.gemini_support]: [1]
[persist.radio.ia]: []
[persist.radio.ia-apn]: []
[persist.radio.mobile.data]: [0,0]
[persist.radio.multisim.config]: [dsds]
[persist.radio.reset_on_switch]: [true]
[persist.radio.simswitch]: [1]
[persist.service.acm.enable]: [0]
[persist.service.bdroid.bdaddr]: [22:22:03:1d:82:c9]
[persist.service.stk.shutdown]: [0]
[persist.sys.autostart.enable]: [1]
[persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2]: [libart.so]
[persist.sys.first_time_boot]: [false]
[persist.sys.fp.navigation]: [1]
[persist.sys.highercost]: [0]
[persist.sys.locale]: [fr-FR]
[persist.sys.mute.state]: [2]
[persist.sys.power_saving]: [1]
[persist.sys.pq.adl.idx]: [0]
[persist.sys.pq.shp.idx]: [2]
[persist.sys.profiler_ms]: [0]
[persist.sys.sd.defaultpath]: [/storage/emulated/0]
[persist.sys.setupwizard.active]: [false]
[persist.sys.timezone]: [Europe/Brussels]
[persist.sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[qemu.hw.mainkeys]: [0]
[ril.active.md]: [5]
[ril.cdma.switching]: [0]
[ril.current.share_modem]: [2]
[ril.data.allow]: [0]
[ril.ecc.service.category.list]: []
[ril.ecclist]: []
[ril.ecclist1]: []
[ril.external.md]: [0]
[ril.fd.mode]: [1]
[ril.first.md]: [1]
[ril.flightmode.poweroffMD]: [1]
[ril.ia.iccid]: []
[ril.iccid.sim1]: [N/A]
[ril.iccid.sim2]: [N/A]
[ril.imsi.status.sim1]: [0]
[ril.imsi.status.sim2]: [0]
[ril.ipo.radiooff]: [0]
[ril.ipo.radiooff.2]: [0]
[ril.mux.ee.md1]: [0]
[ril.mux.report.case]: [0]
[ril.pid.1]: [1894]
[ril.radio.ia]: []
[ril.radio.ia-apn]: []
[ril.radiooff.poweroffMD]: [0]
[ril.read.imsi]: [1]
[ril.ready.sim]: [false]
[ril.specific.sm_cause]: [0]
[ril.telephony.mode]: [0]
[rild.libargs]: [-d /dev/ttyC0]
[rild.libpath]: [mtk-ril.so]
[rild.mark_switchuser]: [0]
[ro.adb.secure]: [1]
[ro.allow.mock.location]: [0]
[ro.asus.audiowizard.outdoor]: [1]
[ro.asus.theme.enable]: [1]
[ro.audio.silent]: [0]
[ro.baseband]: [unknown]
[ro.board.platform]: [mt6737m]
[ro.boot.bootreason]: [wdt_by_pass_pwk]
[ro.boot.config.CID]: [ASUS]
[ro.boot.config.idcode]: [4J]
[ro.boot.config.revenuecountry]: [SG]
[ro.boot.config.versatility]: [WW]
[ro.boot.fptype]: [afs121]
[ro.boot.hardware]: [mt6735]
[ro.boot.isn]: [E28CC6B2604944]
[ro.boot.mode]: [normal]
[ro.boot.name]: [android]
[ro.boot.serialno]: [GBAXGY16K66457B]
[ro.bootimage.build.date]: [Sun Mar 26 22:11:19 CST 2017]
[ro.bootimage.build.date.utc]: [1490537479]
[ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint]: [asus/WW_Phone/ASUS_X008_1:6.0/MRA58K/WW_Phone-13.1.0.56-20170326:user/release-keys]
[ro.bootloader]: [unknown]
[ro.bootmode]: [normal]
[ro.build.asus.sku]: [WW]
[ro.build.asus.version]: [13.1.0.56]
[ro.build.batterymaster]: [1]
[ro.build.characteristics]: [default]
[ro.build.csc.version]: [WW_Phone-13.1.0.56-20170326]
[ro.build.date]: [Sun Mar 26 22:06:01 CST 2017]
[ro.build.date.utc]: [1490537161]
[ro.build.description]: [full_D281L-user 6.0 MRA58K 1490536899 release-keys]
[ro.build.display.id]: [MRA58K.WW_Phone-13.1.0.56-20170326]
[ro.build.fingerprint]: [asus/WW_Phone/ASUS_X008_1:6.0/MRA58K/WW_Phone-13.1.0.56-20170326:user/release-keys]
[ro.build.flavor]: [full_D281L-user]
[ro.build.host]: [SOFT30-13]
[ro.build.id]: [MRA58K]
[ro.build.product]: [ASUS_X008D]
[ro.build.tags]: [release-keys]
[ro.build.type]: [user]
[ro.build.user]: [lishunbo]
[ro.build.version.all_codenames]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.base_os]: []
[ro.build.version.codename]: [REL]
[ro.build.version.incremental]: [WW_Phone-13.1.0.56-20170326]
[ro.build.version.preview_sdk]: [0]
[ro.build.version.release]: [6.0]
[ro.build.version.sdk]: [23]
[ro.build.version.security_patch]: [2017-01-05]
[ro.build.wind.version]: [Plat:ASUS_X008D_37E_WW_V1.0B18Outer:MRA58K.WW_Phone-13.1.0.56-20170326End]
[ro.camera.sound.forced]: [0]
[ro.carrier]: [unknown]
[ro.com.android.dateformat]: [MM/dd/yyyy]
[ro.com.android.mobiledata]: [false]
[ro.com.google.clientidbase]: [android-asus-wypm]
[ro.com.google.clientidbase.am]: [android-asus-wypm]
[ro.com.google.clientidbase.gmm]: [android-asus-wypm]
[ro.com.google.clientidbase.ms]: [android-asus-wypm]
[ro.com.google.clientidbase.yt]: [android-asus-wypm]
[ro.com.google.gmsversion]: [6.0_r11]
[ro.config.CID]: [ASUS]
[ro.config.alarm_alert]: [BusyBugs.ogg]
[ro.config.hwrlib]: [T9_arm]
[ro.config.idcode]: [4J]
[ro.config.notification_sound]: [NewMessage.ogg]
[ro.config.revenuecountry]: [SG]
[ro.config.ringtone]: [Festival.ogg]
[ro.config.versatility]: [WW]
[ro.config.xt9ime.max_subtype]: [7]
[ro.cpufreq]: [1.25GHz]
[ro.crypto.fs_crypto_blkdev]: [/dev/block/dm-1]
[ro.crypto.state]: [encrypted]
[ro.custom.build.version]: [WW_Phone-13.1.0.56-20170326]
[ro.dalvik.vm.native.bridge]: [0]
[ro.debuggable]: [0]
[ro.deviceid]: [354224080156720]
[ro.epad.model]: [ASUS_X008D]
[ro.expect.recovery_id]: [0xeb341637cf0f1eb0ffba09806be31f9e24005a26000000000000000000000000]
[ro.frp.pst]: [/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.msdc0/by-name/frp]
[ro.gemini.smart_sim_switch]: [false]
[ro.hardware]: [mt6735]
[ro.hardware.fp_position]: [back]
[ro.have_aacencode_feature]: [1]
[ro.have_aee_feature]: [1]
[ro.ime.lowmemory]: [false]
[ro.isn]: [E28CC6B2604944]
[ro.kernel.zio]: [38,108,105,16]
[ro.mediatek.chip_ver]: [WK3ME1B4-2]
[ro.mediatek.gemini_support]: [true]
[ro.mediatek.platform]: [MT6737M]
[ro.mediatek.project.path]: [device/ginreen/D281L]
[ro.mediatek.version.branch]: [alps-mp-m0.mp1]
[ro.mediatek.version.release]: [alps-mp-m0.mp1-V2.84_gr6737m.65.m0_P111]
[ro.mediatek.version.sdk]: [4]
[ro.mediatek.wlan.p2p]: [1]
[ro.mediatek.wlan.wsc]: [1]
[ro.mount.fs]: [EXT4]
[ro.mtk_agps_app]: [1]
[ro.mtk_audenh_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_audio_ape_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_audio_profiles]: [1]
[ro.mtk_audio_tuning_tool_ver]: [V1]
[ro.mtk_besloudness_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_bessurround_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_bg_power_saving_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_bg_power_saving_ui]: [1]
[ro.mtk_bip_scws]: [1]
[ro.mtk_bt_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_cam_mfb_support]: [0]
[ro.mtk_dhcpv6c_wifi]: [1]
[ro.mtk_dialer_search_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_dual_mic_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_eap_sim_aka]: [1]
[ro.mtk_emmc_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_enable_md1]: [1]
[ro.mtk_fd_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_flight_mode_power_off_md]: [1]
[ro.mtk_flv_playback_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_fm_recording_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_gemini_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_gmo_ram_optimize]: [1]
[ro.mtk_gps_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_hetcomm_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_is_tablet]: [0]
[ro.mtk_lte_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_matv_analog_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_miravision_image_dc]: [1]
[ro.mtk_miravision_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_oma_drm_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_omacp_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_passpoint_r1_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_perf_fast_start_win]: [1]
[ro.mtk_perf_response_time]: [1]
[ro.mtk_perf_simple_start_win]: [1]
[ro.mtk_perfservice_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_pq_support]: [2]
[ro.mtk_rild_read_imsi]: [1]
[ro.mtk_search_db_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_send_rr_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_shared_sdcard]: [1]
[ro.mtk_sim_hot_swap]: [1]
[ro.mtk_sim_hot_swap_common_slot]: [1]
[ro.mtk_tetheringipv6_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_thumbnail_play_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_voice_contact_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_voice_extension_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_wapi_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_wappush_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_widevine_drm_l3_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_wifi_mcc_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_wlan_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_wmv_playback_support]: [1]
[ro.mtk_world_phone_policy]: [0]
[ro.opengles.version]: [196608]
[ro.product.board]: [MT6737]
[ro.product.brand]: [asus]
[ro.product.carrier]: [US-ASUS_X008_1-WW_Phone]
[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [arm64-v8a]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist]: [arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist32]: [armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist64]: [arm64-v8a]
[ro.product.device]: [ASUS_X008_1]
[ro.product.first_api_level]: [23]
[ro.product.hardware]: [WK3ME1B4-2]
[ro.product.locale]: [en-US]
[ro.product.locale.region]: [US]
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [asus]
[ro.product.minmatch]: [7]
[ro.product.model]: [ASUS_X008D]
[ro.product.name]: [WW_Phone]
[ro.recovery_id]: [0xeb341637cf0f1eb0ffba09806be31f9e24005a26000000000000000000000000]
[ro.revision]: [0]
[ro.runtime.firstboot]: [1451624440026]
[ro.secure]: [1]
[ro.serialno]: [GBAXGY16K66457B]
[ro.setting.dateformat]: [MM/dd/yyyy]
[ro.setupwizard.mode]: [OPTIONAL]
[ro.sf.hwrotation]: [0]
[ro.sf.lcd_density]: [320]
[ro.sim_me_lock_mode]: [0]
[ro.sys.incalltime]: [150]
[ro.sys.usb.bicr]: [yes]
[ro.sys.usb.charging.only]: [yes]
[ro.sys.usb.mtp.whql.enable]: [0]
[ro.sys.usb.storage.type]: [mtp,mass_storage]
[ro.telephony.sim.count]: [2]
[ro.update.battery_threshold]: [15]
[ro.wifi.channels]: []
[ro.wind.asus_demo_app]: [1]
[ro.wind.dateformat.is.12]: [0]
[ro.wind.dateformat.is.24]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.adapt_asus_apk_ww]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asus.camera]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asus.gestures]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asus.gsensor]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asus.hardware]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asus.notdisturb]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asus.powersaver]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asus.systemui]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asus_bluelight]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asus_preloaded]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asus_storage]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asus_usb_dialog]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asuscellbroadcast]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.asussettings]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.aviod_touch]: [0]
[ro.wind.def.call_do_later]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.cm.weather]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.custom.def.vol]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.flipfont.ww]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.fota.del.finger]: [0]
[ro.wind.def.kids.mode]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.mobi_man.enable]: [1]
[ro.wind.def.motion_support]: [1]
[...] I can provide this part if necessary. Otherwise question is too long...
-- End GetProperties --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS" -e "packages" "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime,Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24,com.companyname.App123123465" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions"
-- Start Broadcast - 04/15/2017 23:34:33 (1157.2355ms) --
[INPUT] am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS" -e "packages" "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime,Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24,com.companyname.App123123465" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions"
[OUTPUT]
Broadcasting: Intent { act=mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS cmp=Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
-- End Broadcast --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B cat /data/system/packages.xml
-- Start GetPackages - 04/15/2017 23:34:34 (14.1293ms) --
[INPUT] cat /data/system/packages.xml
[OUTPUT]
/system/bin/sh: cat: /data/system/packages.xml: Permission denied
-- End GetPackages --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
-- Start GetPackages - 04/15/2017 23:34:34 (14.5395ms) --
[INPUT] cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
[OUTPUT]
/system/bin/sh: cat: /dbdata/system/packages.xml: No such file or directory
-- End GetPackages --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B pm uninstall "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime"
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B pm uninstall "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime"
-- Start UninstallPackage - 04/15/2017 23:34:34 (1368.2551ms) --
[INPUT] pm uninstall "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime"
[OUTPUT]
Success
-- End UninstallPackage --
-- Start UninstallPackage - 04/15/2017 23:34:34 (1503.441ms) --
[INPUT] pm uninstall "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime"
[OUTPUT]
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
-- End UninstallPackage --
-- Start Push - 04/15/2017 23:34:36 (9660.3228ms) --
[INPUT] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk : /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
[OUTPUT]
Completed
-- End Push --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B pm install "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk"
-- Start InstallPackage - 04/15/2017 23:34:45 (12857.1355ms) --
[INPUT] pm install "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk"
[OUTPUT]
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
Success
-- End InstallPackage --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B rm "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk"
-- Start DeleteFile - 04/15/2017 23:34:58 (77.7241ms) --
[INPUT] rm "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk"
[OUTPUT]

-- End DeleteFile --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS" -e "packages" "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime,Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24,com.companyname.App123123465" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions"
-- Start Broadcast - 04/15/2017 23:34:58 (1288.8691ms) --
[INPUT] am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS" -e "packages" "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime,Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24,com.companyname.App123123465" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions"
[OUTPUT]
Broadcasting: Intent { act=mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS cmp=Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
-- End Broadcast --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B cat /data/system/packages.xml
-- Start GetPackages - 04/15/2017 23:35:00 (13.9134ms) --
[INPUT] cat /data/system/packages.xml
[OUTPUT]
/system/bin/sh: cat: /data/system/packages.xml: **Permission denied**
-- End GetPackages --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
-- Start GetPackages - 04/15/2017 23:35:00 (12.1516ms) --
[INPUT] cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
[OUTPUT]
/system/bin/sh: cat: /dbdata/system/packages.xml: **No such file or directory**
-- End GetPackages --
[D:RunShellCommand]:   GBAXGY16K66457B "pm" "list" "packages" "-f"
-- Start GetPackagesLastResort - 04/15/2017 23:35:00 (1528.1461ms) --
[INPUT] "pm" "list" "packages" "-f"
[OUTPUT]
[...] I can provide this part if necessary. Otherwise question is too long...
-- End GetPackagesLastResort --
[E:]: Deployment failed
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidInstalledPackage..ctor(String value)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.ParseLastResortPackageList(String output)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass65_0.<GetPackagesLastResort>b__0(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue occur when your debug version is signed with a different key than your installed version. Try removing the application from the device and running it from debug mode. This will automatically sign the application with the debug key.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I forgot to say that I reset the android phone and I still get the problem. However that's an input that I will keep in mind. Maybe it is related.